# SQL : get row with MIN(date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the row with the **MIN(c.date_debut)**, I did this, but I get a

> Invalid use of group function

```
select distinct num_facture, s.nom, f.montant_ht, a.regle_client, a.date_reglement_effectif_client, a.type_ligne
from facture f, mission m, activite a, commande c , societe_client s
where f.activite_id = a.id and a.mission_id = m.id and m.id = c.mission_id 
and m.client_id = s.id
and min(c.date_debut)
and a.type_ligne in  ('Forfait','Presta')
and a.annee_id>=4
and s.nom like '%capgemini%'
group by num_facture, s.nom, f.montant_ht, a.regle_client, a.date_reglement_effectif_client, a.type_ligne
```

If anyone can help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select . . .
from . . .
order by date asc
limit 1;
```